# TASM SIMPLE LOOP implemention

Tags: for-loop, tasm

I just want too write simple .asm code for TASM that work as for in C++

```
int t=2;
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
t=t+(i-1)*7*t;
```

How can I implement it with TASM?

Comment: Please show what you have so far

Comment: I just want to know how to program with TASM with a simple example...I didn't write anything with TASM before

Comment: It's generally considered good form to have a go at it yourself first before asking. Go google "tasm for loop" and see what you can find out yourself. Have a go. Tell us whether it worked or not... then get back to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will loop from 1 to 100 in 8086 TASM:

```
    .MODEL SMALL

    .STACK 100h

    .DATA   
    Finished DB 10, 13, 'Loop x 100 finished.  Congratulations! $', 10, 13

    .CODE

    MAIN PROC

            MOV AX, @data            ; Required at the start of every program (inside your main procedure, from what I've seen)
            MOV DS, AX

            MOV CX, 100              ; Set CX to 100
            MOV BX, 0                ; Counter (for double-verification, I guess...lol)

    StrtLoop:                        ; When a loop starts, it does CX-- (subtracts 1 from CX)   

            INC BX                    ; This does BX++, which increments BX by 1

    LOOP StrtLoop                     ; Go back to StrtLoop label

            CMP BX, 100              ; Compare BX to 100...
            JE DispMsg               ; Jump-if-Equal...CMP BX, 100 sets flags, and if they are set,
                                     ;  JE will Jump you to DispMsg (to get "congratulations" message).

            JMP SkipMsg              ; Jump to the SkipMsg label (so you don't see the "congratulations" message).

    DispMsg:                         ; If BX = 100, you JE here.
            MOV AH, 09H              ; Displays the message stored in the defined byte "Finished"
            MOV DX, OFFSET Finished
            INT 21H
    SkipMsg:                         ; If BX != 100, you JMP here.
            MOV AL, 0h               ; Op code to exit to DOS from the assembler.
            MOV AH, 4CH
            INT 21H

    MAIN ENDP
    END MAIN
```

I hope it helps.  I did the basic loop, so you can do the other bits of your code (and I don't know C++, lol).  Good luck!  It's hard, but kind of fun at the same time (at least for me).

Comment: Btw, DOS function 9 will not print anything beyond the "$" character. So, either the last CR/LF pair is unnecessary or should go before "$".